# HTML doc is way to zoomed in and scaled improperly when ran on an android device

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I am working on a project for my AP CS course where we have to clone an app that we use on a daily basis. I am doing CashApp. I opted to make the app mobile by using VoltBuilder which is basically like PhoneGap. You upload a zipped file of the HTML, CSS, and JS, and it compiles it into an APK for android. However, when I run the APK it looks super zoomed in and the scale is totally off. This is not exclusive to just the android, it also does it in the mobile viewer in the Chrome dev tools. Any suggestions to make it scale properly? The design is responsive, so I don't know why it's acting weird.

Problem in DevTools: issue in devtools mobile view

[image]

Problem on android emulator: issue on android emulator

[image]

```js
document.getElementById('backspace').addEventListener('click', backspace)
let fired_button
let moneyval = document.getElementById('money')
$("button").click(function() {
  fired_button = $(this).val();
  let emptyArray = []
  emptyArray.push(moneyval.textContent)
  console.log(emptyArray)
  for (var i = 0; i < emptyArray.length; i++) {
    if (emptyArray[0] == "$0") {
      moneyval.textContent = "$" + fired_button
    } else {
      moneyval.textContent += fired_button
    }

  }

});


function backspace() {
  console.log(moneyval.textContent)
  let string = moneyval.textContent
  string = string.substring(0, string.length - 1);
  moneyval.textContent = string


}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
body {
    background-color: blue;
    font-family: 'Inter';
}

#camera,
#search,
#profile {
  background-color: blue;
  color: black;
  border: 0;
}

.camera {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.search {
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.head-section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
}

.head-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 40px;
  top: 60px;
}

.money {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87);
  font-size: 150px;
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 182px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
}

.usd {
  position: absolute;
  width: 146.4px;
  height: 61px;
  background: #0CC337;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
  border-radius: 43px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-style: none;
}

.numberpad {
  position: relative;
  width: 850px;
  height: 540px;
  top: 180px;
}

.row1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.row2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.row3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.row4 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.row1,
.row2,
.row3,
.row4 {
  margin-top: 80px;
}

button {
  border-style: none;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.subcta {
  border-style: solid;
  position: relative;
}

.sub-cta {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 750px;
  height: 124px;
  top: 230px;

  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.sub-button {
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 1.3em;
  padding: .3em;
  background-color: black;
  border-color: #0CC337;
  width: 293px;
  height: 88px;
}

.balance-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 720px;
  height: 219px;
  top: 200px;
}

main {
    width:100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=yes">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale= 1.0">
    <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script defer src="./js/index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="head-section">
    <button id="camera"> <a href="#"><img src="./img/image 1.png" alt=""></a></button>
    <button id="search"> <a href="#"><img src="./img/image 2.png" alt=""></a></button>
  </div>

  <div class="head-right">
    <button id="profile"><img src="./img/image 3.png" alt=""></button>
  </div>
  <main>
      <div class="balance-container">
        <h1 id="money" class="money">$0</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
      </div>
      <section class="numberpad">
        <div class="row1">
          <button class="numpad" name="1" id="1" value="1">1</button>
          <button name="2" id="2" value="2">2</button>
          <button name="3" id="3" value="3">3</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row2">
          <button name="4" id="4" value="4">4</button>
          <button name="5" id="5" value="5">5</button>
          <button name="6" id="6" value="6">6</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row3">
          <button name="7" id="7" value="7">7</button>
          <button name="8" id="8" value="8">8</button>
          <button name="9" id="9" value="9">9</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row4">
          <button name="." id="." value=".">.</button>
          <button name="0" id="0" value="0">0</button>
          <button id="backspace">&#60;</button>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="sub-cta">
        <div>
          <button class="sub-button">Request</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button id="pay" class="sub-button">Pay</button>
        </div>
      </section>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem responsive.  It looks like you hard code all the widths to pixel values - the interpolated pixel width of most phones is 360px, and you have things that are 700+.  The dollar sign has a font size of 150px(!) which is massive.

Comment: But your code isn't responsive? You're using an absolute unit with `px` which is fine but if you tell the browser this object needs to be 150px x 150px that's how it's going to render regardless of the device it's on unless you target that object and its properties in a `@media` query https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Responsive_Design 

Here's an explanation of units and which are absolute versus relative and how you can utilize them to create a responsive page: https://getflywheel.com/layout/choose-css-unit-create-better-site-layouts-how-to/

Comment: Ok so I should use relative units like em instead and that should fix the problem?

Comment: I'd suggest two or more css files (one for desktop, one for mobile, etc) with media queries.  Then you can use px if you like (just use smaller values for the mobile css)

Comment: That's kind of an opinion thing but changing everything to em isn't going to completely solve your initial concern. I like to use https://gist.github.com/basham/2175a16ab7c60ce8e001 as a cheat sheet and that's always worked for me. You'll probably still end up needing some media queries though if you want to have specific control over the layout on various devices.

Comment: It looks like you font sizes are a bit big but I can't tell from the screen shots what is being scaled so large. Are they images or HTML elements? To check it isn't a problem with your Android settings simplify the code down to one element for testing and then add in other elements and styles once you have one element looking correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a "@media only screen and (max-width: 450px){...}" into your css

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a couple of days ago and I found out that it has something to do with your device pixel ratio. See, one pixel in CSS is not one physical pixel on your phone, it is 1/96th of an inch. If you just want the version of your project to run on just one device, find out what your device pixel ratio is and divide every pixel by that. For example, I have a Xiaomi Redmi Note 9 pro with a screen resolution of 1080p x 2400p but the device pixel ratio is 2.75. That means in HTML/CSS I have to divide every pixel by 2.75 (the resolution on my browser window is now 1080/2.75 and 2430/2.75 -> 393p x 873p).

Just adjust your pixel sizes and your images height and width and your good to go.

To find out your device pixel ratio:

Go to this link: https://yesviz.com/viewport/